# How do i add the values in a 2d array using a for loop in python

Tags: python, arrays, loops

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

scores = [[8, 1], [5, 3], [3, 5], [8, 1], [7, 1], [1, 0], [9, 0], [5, 0], [6, 0], [8, 1, 0]]
#scores_int = 0;
#scores_int = len(scores);
sum = 0;


for row in range(len(scores)):
    sum = scores[0]
print(sum)
print(scores[0:1])
print(scores[1][0])
   #print("Sum of all all the socres:", sum);
```

So im trying to figure out a way to loop through every instance of the array and add the values in them to a sum variable, but i dont understand how to loop through a 2d array. The score sum should equal 72
i just need syntax help with the for loop

Answer (score 1):

My advice if you're begginer is just to experiment with things you don't know.
Next time you could print all the list of numbers and then try to sum it , avg it, or count the numbers inside it

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    scores = [[8, 1], [5, 3], [3, 5], [8, 1], [7, 1], [1, 0], [9, 0], [5, 0], [6, 0], [8, 1, 0]]
    total = 0
    
    for list_of_number in scores:
        # print(list_of_number)
        total += sum(list_of_number)
    
    print(total)
```

Comment: Thanks Michael for your advice, and ive been experimenting for the past two days. I just hit a wall. Thank you for your help!